# Let $G$ be a finite group and $T$ be a cyclic $p$-subgroup of $G$, assume that $E\le N_G(T)$ and $|E|\mid p-1$, Is it true that $C_T(E)=1$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups

Question:

> Let $G$ be a finite group and $T$ be a cyclic $p$-subgroup of $G$, where $p$ is an odd prime, assume that $E\le N_G(T)$ and $|E|\mid p-1$, Is it true that $C_T(E)=1$?

It is a step in a Lemma on a paper of Journal of Algebra, but I can't deal with it.

[The number of irreducible Brauer characters
in a p-block of a finite group with cyclic hyperfocal
subgroup-Atumi Watanabe] Lemma 4(i) Line 4-5

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: On MSE, we'd like to see effort. Have you tried the problem yourself? What approaches have you tried?

Comment: I spent a few hours on it, but I can't find a possible approach at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $G = \{1,g,g^2,s,sg,sg^2 : sg = gs\}$

Then we can have $p = 3$, $T=\{1,g,g^2\}$ and $E=\{1,s\}$, $C_T(E) = T$ and $|E|  \ | \ p-1$ and $N_G(T) = G$ and hence $C_T(E) \neq \{1\}$